# Using substitutions in snippets in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm trying to understand how the following snippet in Sublime Text 2 works, which I found in the LaTeX folder:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[\\begin{${1:env}}
    ${1/(enumerate|itemize|list)|(description)|.*/(?1:\item )(?2:\item)/}$0
\\end{${1:env}}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>begin</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
    <description>\begin{}…\end{}</description>
</snippet>
```

Now I'm familiar with what, basically, the `${1:env}` does, but I'm not clear on what `${1/(enumerate|itemize|list)|(description)|.*/(?1:\item )(?2:\item)/}` does.  I tried looking it up and I know how `1` selects the text in `$1{env}` and the next thing is a regular expression, etc.  But what happens?  How does functionality change if I just remove this part?

Comment: It looks like it's doing a substitution, of what I don't know. `/find/replace/`

Answer (score 0):

I see at least some of the functionality now, after playing with it for a little longer.  Suppose you use this code to build an enumerate environment.  After you've typed `enumerate` and hit `Tab`, the `${1/(enumerate|itemize|list)|(description)|.*/(?1:\item )(?2:\item)/}` will automatically put an `item` inside the environment.  I think it's a mistake that it doesn't produce `\item`, but not a big deal.  In any case, the rest of the functionality is that, from here, if you type `Shift+Enter` it'll produce a line break and another `\item` automatically.

I'm not super clear on exactly what part of this code is responsible for each part of this behavior--for instance I'm not sure how the `(?2\item)` bit works since there is no place-holder numbered 2--but that's the basic functionality.